# getCurrentSession().flush() should be in Dao

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dao

I have a simple question for you about `Hibernate` and `Spring`.

I have `Dao` classes with `update`, `delete`, `save`, etc...

I want to unitary test them, and particulary on constraint.

So for that I try to update an element with wrong value.

BUT, for update in particulary, if I don't add `flush()` into `dao`, no exception is thrown. -> Normal, cause database don't check it.

But I don't want put `flush` in my `dao` !

How you do that ?

Comment: If you're using Spring, just use Spring Data and don't write DAOs yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you use sprin-data, then let your Repository (Dao) extend `JpaRepository` (http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html) , then you can just call its `flush()` method if necessary after you have called update, save, delete etc...

Comment: Thank you but I don't ask how to make a dao (in fact i use spring data hibernate), just the good practice for flush. I want to let hibernate manage it, but i need it in unitary test of add and update. Should I call flush in unitary test ?

Comment: If you use spring data, then I wonder why you want to test update, delete etc, because you have not implemented these methods yourself. Spring should test the correctness those method. You should test the methods that YOU have written

Comment: A Dao is a class which use those function... that's why I want to test it. And again, the question is not about what I did, but only where to put flush for unitary test...